# Boost C++ - generating a random real number between 0 and 1

Tags: c++, boost, random

I've been reading the Boost C++ documentation and trying to figure out how to generate a random real number between 0 and 1, using the `uniform_01` part of the library. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Based on suggestions, I'm using this code, but it generates the same random value every time.

```
double random01(mt19937 & generator)
{
    uniform_01<mt19937> dist(generator);
    return dist();
}

int main()
{
    mt19937 generator(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << random01(generator) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if I wasn't clear; this question isn't solved, by my answer or any other. It's still generating the same random value each time.

Comment: If this is a self-answer, you should have posted it as a question first. This solution should then have been posted as an answer later on.

Comment: Better rewrite it as a question "how to generate a random real number between 0 and 1", and an answer below.

Comment: Will do; thank you. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: One last thing: mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few 'gotcha's in this code:

1. The `random01()` function does not take a reference to the generator, but rather a *copy* of the generator. So if you call the function multiple times with the same generator - it will produce the same value over and over again!
2. The `static` `uniform_01` in `random01()` only gets initialized on the first call to random01, so if it is ever called with a different generator, it will not use it, but rather use a reference to the first generator, which may even have been destroyed, since!

Correct would be something like following (note the `&` in the arguments list, for pass-by-reference, and the lack of `static`:

```
double random01(mt19937 & generator)
{
    uniform_01<mt19937> dist(generator);
    return dist();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help; when I generate a sequence of values in a loop using that code, the value generated is the same every time. I can't post code properly in a comment, but I simply wrapped the `cout` statement in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

using boost::mt19937;
using boost::uniform_01;

double random01(mt19937 generator)
{
    static uniform_01<mt19937> dist(generator);
    return dist();
}

int main()
{
    mt19937 generator(time(0));
    cout << random01(generator) << endl;

}
```

The code is slightly modified from [here](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/cpp-boost-uniform01.html); hat tip to Bojan Nikolic.

I posted this as a "solution" in the hope that it helps someone, but please criticise anything you notice wrong with it. I tried to separate the seeding step from the actual generation so the twister isn't seeded every single time it generates a value.

Comment: You can do this with c++11 stl rather than boost if you have c++11

Comment: Right. The version of Linux I'm using doesn't use g++ 4.6 by default (I think that's the compiler that includes much support for for c++11) and I was trying to avoid compiling g++ from the source code.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 x64. According to apt, it's version 4.5.2 in the repositories. I wasn't sure if that had support for C++11, and I wasn't aware of the random number functions in C++11 until this afternoon; I may investigate those later.

Comment: on my Ubuntu I always compiled gcc, its really easy on Ubuntu

Comment: That's what I've heard; I just started working with C++ yesterday, so I haven't had the necessity yet. I might give that a run later today.