# boost c++ is generating the same random number between 0 and 1, using the Mersenne Twister algorithm?

Tags: c++, boost, random

I'm trying to generate a random real number between 0 and 1, using the Boost C++ `uniform_01` functions and the Mersenne Twister algorithm. This is my code:

```
double random01(mt19937 & generator)
{
    uniform_01<mt19937> dist(generator);
    return dist();
}

int main()
{
    mt19937 generator(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << random01(generator) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, this code generates the same random number on every iteration of the loop. I know this is a repeat of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202694/boost-c-generating-a-random-real-number-between-0-and-1), but that question was closed for being ambiguous, so I rephrased it.

Comment: Try taking the `uniform_01` out of the loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not quite how you use a distribution. More like this:

```
#include <random>
#define abusing using

abusing namespace std;

double random01(mt19937 & engine)
{
  uniform_real_distribution<double> u01; // same as u01(0.0, 1.0); see Note below
  return u01(engine);
}

int main()
{
  // as before
}
```

As you can see, the distribution object is independent of everything else, so in fact you might like to make it a global, or perhaps a static variable.

(Note that `uniform_01` didn't make it into the final standard, but instead `uniform_real_distribution`'s default constructor defaults to the interval [0, 1]. For the old Boost class you can use the analogous approach.)

Comment: That's working perfectly, and thanks for the note about the documentation; I hadn't realised that `uniform_01` isn't an official part of the distribution, but it's probably best that I'm using the more general `uniform_real` regardless.

Comment: @pythonscript: Well, as long as you're locked into Boost it doesn't matter so much, but if you want to migrate to `std` eventually, it's good to pick up the right habits! :-) The `<random>` interface has undergone several changes since TR1 and Boost, so it's worth reading up. In particular, all engines are now called `_engine`, and all distributions `_distribution`. Oh, whoops, I actually got that wrong, let me fix!

Comment: Your updated code gives me an error in Eclipse, though, whether or not I use `#include <random>`. Should I post more code, or just stick with the original way you suggested? I want to learn the best habits sooner rather than further, if at all possible.

Comment: @pythonscript: Just pick whichever version works. C++11 says it's `uniform_real_distribution`, but the Boost version is different, and the `<tr1/random>` version is also different -- just check which one you want and take the one that works :-)

Comment: That makes a lot more sense; I'll explore the other options while I'm working on a simple project before locking myself in too firmly to any library in particular. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Create the  uniform_01 outside the function. You need to work on the same instance to get consecutive numbers. Alternatively you can make that static.